# Dynamically Change Path of Data Connection in Excel

Tags: excel, box, data-connections

I developed a workbook that uses Power Query to import data from two CSV files that are saved in a Box Sync folder on my desktop. Box is a cloud storage service that routinely syncs data stored in the cloud on the user's desktop.

When another user attempts to open the workbook I created and refresh the data they are unable to because the data connections to the two csv files are absolute references to the Box Sync folder on my desktop. I believe this problem can be solved if I can find a way to dynamically update a portion of the data connection's file path in Excel.

For example:

Box Sync folders have the same file structure the only difference being the desktop reference portion of the path:

My Box Sync Folder Path:
C:\Users\user.a\Box Sync\ParentFolder\SubFolder\2018\csvfile.csv

Other User's Box Sync Path:
C:\Users\user.b\Box Sync\ParentFolder\SubFolder\2018\csvfile.csv

What I need to be able to do is dynamically update the 
'C:\Users\user.b' portion of the path in the data connection string.

Your help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi - I appreciate this is over 2 years ago - but did you get anywhere with this, as it sounds very similar to what I need to do ?